# Sql queries - MySql error unexpected IDENT_QUOTED

Tags: mysql, database, triggers

I was writing a SQL trigger for a college job when the error IDENT_QUOTED appeared in statement "temp entiresponsavel% ROWTYPE;" in the code below.
I'm using MySql 5.5. Does anyone know why this is happening?

```
CREATE TRIGGER `Responsavel` 
BEFORE INSERT ON `exposicao` 
FOR EACH ROW
begin
    declare
    entiresponsavel cursor for (select nome from Museu);
    temp entiresponsavel%ROWTYPE;
    open entiresponsavel;
    while (entiresponsavel%found) loop
        begin
            fetch from entiresponsavel into temp; 
            if (new.entidade_respon = temp)
                begin
                    SET new.curadorExpo = pessoa(temp);
                end if;
        end loop;
    close entiresponsavel;
end;
```

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think MySQL supports `%ROWTYPE`. Where in the manual did you see this?

Comment: Can you post the exact error message to aid in debugging?

Comment: a_horse_with_no_name, thank you!